# Source Path too long

Tags: windows, git, delete-file

I am getting this error while deleting my git local branch from windows machine. 
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you attempt to delete the branch? Do you run some command on the command line? If so, why? Or do you use some UI (e.g. Tortoise Git)?

Comment: I am physically deleting files from windows directory which contains local git branch.

Comment: It sounds like your question is rather something for superuser.com; [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/256105/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-which-is-nested-quite-deep-and-avoid-file-name-too-lon) seems to be duplicated by yours.

Comment: JFTR, you can use `Alt+PrnScr` to capture just the window which has focus -- this could save you from pointless cropping in an image editor afterwards. Another point is that Windows' dialog boxes support `Ctrl+C` directly: so when you have such dialog focused, just `Ctrl+C` in it and then paste the obtained text somewhere.